# Does the outline algorithm in WHATWG work in the browser?

Tags: html, language-lawyer, w3c

W3C's HTML5.2 specification merged with WHATWG's HTML Standard.

https://www.w3.org/blog/news/archives/7753

Here, I noticed what was left out of the WHATWG specification, such as outline algorithms that were incomplete in W3C, rb, and rtc elements, and those that were deleted. This is a question about the outline algorithm.

---

**Question**

In W3C HTML5.2, the following warning clearly indicated that the outline algorithm was theoretical in specification. As a result, I learned that the browser did not implement the outline algorithm.

> There are currently no known native implementations of the outline algorithm in graphical browsers or assistive technology user agents, although the algorithm is implemented in other software such as conformance checkers and browser extensions. Therefore the outline algorithm cannot be relied upon to convey document structure to users. Authors should use heading rank (h1-h6) to convey document structure.
>
> <sup>ref --- https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sections.html#creating-an-outline</sup>

However, no such section or warning was found in the [WHATWG HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html).

Does this indicate that the browser has a complete outline algorithm implemented? Or are the outline algorithms and hgroup elements still incompatible with browsers and are the specifications incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

They are still not supported by browsers (besides the default styling of H1 elements). There is an issue against the WHATWG specification on GitHub (https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/83) and several attempts to fix it, but none of them has succeeded yet.